# Linq: Difference between 2 DateTimes in TimeSpan

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do this:

```
Tickets.Where(t => (t.Date - myTicket.Date) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

I'm getting the "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type" error. How can I do this, considering that I need the difference in a TimeSpan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you connecting to?  Is this linq to SQL, EF, are you expecting this to be done in memory? Edit: noticed there is a tag for it; would be helpful to mention something that important in the body of the question though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would want to use [SqlFunctions.DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052.aspx)

```
Tickets.Where(t => 
      SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second", t.Date, myTicket.Date) < 120));
```

Comment: please tell me, what is the meaning of "second" word in your above code, and is it returning number of days or not...??? please mention me in your answer...

Comment: @RahulChaudhari It is returning the number of second's hence the word "second". If you want days write "day".

Comment: Args switched?  It seems "myTicket.Date" (earlier date) should be before "t.Date" argument.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this;

```
var result = db.Tickets.Where(t => 
       SqlMethods.DateDiffSecond(myTicket.Date ,  t.Date) < 120);
```

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic with DateTime is not supported in Entity Framework. You have to use one of the [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052.aspx). So, for your statement, something like:

```
Tickets.Where(t => 
      SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second", t.Date, myTicket.Date) < 120));
```

Comment: Sorry about the down vote.  Please alter your answer slightly and I can then remove it.